# No agent could be found with the following capabilities: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have TFS On-Premises, and I have this errror when queueing a new build.

No agent could be found with the following capabilities: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest

I found this answer: [No agent could be found with the following capabilities: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840364/no-agent-could-be-found-with-the-following-capabilities-msbuild-visualstudio)

But is there any way to fix it on-premises without installing Visual Studio on the build server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No agent could be found with the following capabilities: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840364/no-agent-could-be-found-with-the-following-capabilities-msbuild-visualstudio)

Comment: Installed only MSBuild and C# compiler from VS  2017 Community RC-> still that error. Installed Build Tools for VS 2017 RC -> still that error. Finally, just installed Desktop development of VS 2017 Com. RC -> Solved. It seems I have to install the full VS, not just build tools. A lot of waste of disk space.

Comment: Hi @LuisValencia did you have TFS2017 on premises? Do I also need to install Visual Studio 2017 on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to install VS on the build server you could add a new build agent and install VS there.

Comment: To your knowledge, does the Community Edition provide the necessary prerequisites for a Build Server configuration?

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll go with Pro just in case. Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with Visual Studio 2017 installed on the build server (on-prem):

> No agent could be found with the followin capabilities msbuild,visualstudio, vstest

When **I upgraded a Test Controller the Build Agent lost some of its capabilities**, such as VSTest:

[image]

I added these capabilities back as User Capabilities:

[image]

```
MSBuild_15.0 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\
MSBuild_15.0_x64 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\
VSTest = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
VSTest_15.0 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow

VisualStudio = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\
VisualStudio_15.0 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\
VisualStudio_IDE = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\
VisualStudio_IDE_15.0 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\
```

Then I got the infamous error:

> MSBuild not found for version '15.0' and architecture 'x86'

I searched the web high and low, I did so many things to try and resolve this issue, I finally found [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/85660/tfs-build-agent-on-premise-fails-to-build-msbuild.html) saying its been fixed in TFS update 2.

I upgraded TFS from update 1 to 2 and that **did fix** the problem.