# TFS 2015:No agent could be found with the following capabilities: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest

Tags: tfs, msbuild, agent

We have recently upgraded to TFS 2015 Update 4. When I tried to do a build, I am getting the following error:

> There are issues with the request or definition that may prevent the build from running:No agent could be found with the following capabilities: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest Queue the build anyway?

I tried the workaround mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840364/no-agent-could-be-found-with-the-following-capabilities-msbuild-visualstudio), but still couldn't figure out.

I have installed VS 2017 Enterprise in the Build Machine. Note, that since this is a POC I have installed Build Agent on the TFS Server itself.
Should anything extra be need to be installed? Please help.

TIA

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for the serverfault SO group.

Comment: Which build are you running the old XAML build or the new vNext build? And did you get any error info in Event View?

Comment: @Patrick I am using Vnext Build. When i remove the "Visual Studio Test Option" from the Build steps, the build runs successfully. What am i missing in my build server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could double check if you are missing some capabilities such as *VSTEST_15.0*  for the build agent.

**Settings- Agent Queues- Agent Pool - Agent- Capabilities**

[image]

If the test related capabilities  are missing, you could try to reregister the build agent. Or manually add the capabilitie by select +.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My agent capability dont have VisualStudio as well as VsTest recognised. So i manually added and now i am able to run the build successfully.i have 2 queries here 1) Why my agent didnt recognised the VS and vstest. Is it because i have installed the trial version since this is a POC machine. 2) My build runs successfully with warning.[warning]Visual Studio version '14.0' not found. Looking for the latest version.
##[warning]Visual Studio not found. Try installing a supported version of Visual Studio. See the task definition for a list of supported versions.

Comment: @Nikitha 1)The system capabilities are only discovered when the agent is first configured -- any changes made after that are not captured. I guess you VS was installed after the build agent configured. 2) For this, maybe your project is created from VS 2015 . Your build agent is using another version VS  and it seems that you choose VS 2015 to build your project in the build definition, so during the build, it will try to find VS 2015(14.0) on build agent.

Comment: @alltej No, you have to use command line for now. Check this for more details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same issue: installed VS2017, configured build agent, visualstudio and msbuild capabilities missing.

**Try installing VS2015 next to VS2017. Re-configure the build agent after this** (in my case, I completely removed all the old _diag, _work and settings.json data as well). This fixed the issue for me, the missing capabilities were now recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error out of the blue and it was running fine the previous week.
Restarting the build agent service resolved the error for me