# How to add Visual Studio 2017 to Team Foundation Server Build Agent?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfs-2015

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 on my server to build projects. The server is running team foundation server 2015 Update 3. The TFS 2015  shows the option as Latest in Visual Studio Version but when I build the project then it don't build and says agent don't have capabilities visualstudio, vstest, msbuild.
I'm trying to manually add capabilities but it don't work and says Visual studio not found.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.  You need a build agent to do a TFS build not visual studio

Comment: @KenTucker I've installed the build agent  and it is running. I want to build a project which requires Visual Studio as Build Agent capability. How can I build that project without Visual Studio capability because whenever I try to build the project, it asks for Visual Studio capability.

Comment: I am finding that TFS build agent v2.112.0 is not recognizing VS2017 at all in terms of capabilities.

Comment: @MattSharpe You are right. I've managed to add VS2017 in TFS but not able to run it correctly. Any thing fails on some point. It is not running correctly

Comment: I found a [new version of the agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases/tag/v2.120.1) which appears to be capable of detecting VS2017.

Comment: @MattSharpe I tried installing this version of Agent with TFS 2015 but it is not compatible with VS TFS 2015 :(

Comment: @MattSharpe —Thanks for the link to the updated agent. Were you able to get the `vstest` capability with this agent? I've now got `visualstudio`, thanks to the update, but not `vstest`.

Comment: @InteXX I have `vstest`, but so far I'm finding that test tasks fail. Just recently updated to TFS 2017 Update 2 - hoping that may help? Haven't had an opportunity to check yet.

Comment: @MattSharpe — I'm down for the count—due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46031290/722393)—but I'll report back here once I get everything straightened out and updated to 2017.2.

Comment: @InteXX With the latest agent, TFS 2017 Update 2, and the "version 2" Test build step, I now have run a successful CI build on an agent with just VS 2017.

Comment: @MattSharpe — I'm back up now, but after installing 2017.2 I'm still unable to get a `VSTest` capability in a new agent. I'm curious... do you have the file `vstest.console.exe` present anywhere on your server? According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19ca4c82-6dc6-47cc-a740-18c01b7d826e/new-build-server-unable-to-determine-the-location-of-vstestconsoleexe?forum=tfsbuild), it seems to be required. I'm not finding it. (FYI I haven't tried a CI build; until I get this straightened out I'm certain it'd fail.)

Comment: @MattSharpe — Two questions: 1) Did your successful CI build include a Test Step? 2) If so, do you have the full IDE installed or just the Build Tools? Also, I'm still curious about whether you have a `vstest.console.exe` on your server (most likely in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow`). If you do, did you get it by installing the full IDE or just the Build Tools? I guess that's actually four questions ;-)

Comment: @InteXX Full Visual Studio is installed on the build agent. `vstest.console.exe` is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow` as detected by the agent and reported in capabilities.

Comment: @MattSharpe — Got it, thanks. Was hoping to get it without the full IDE, but we can't have everything.

Comment: @InteXX I'm not able to install the new build agent with TFS 2015, it says "incompatible build agent, please download the build agent from my tfs url". How did you do that?

Comment: Looking through my comments, I can see that I never indicated my TFS version. I'm on 2017.2.

Comment: @InteXX hmm thanks :)

Comment: YW, hope you get it worked out. In case you're able to consider upgrading to 2017, Jesse Houwing has provided some good advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41391953/722393) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44103985/722393).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your build agent is not installed on the same machine with your TFS server(which VS2017 installed).
Give a try with **install Visual Studio on your *build agent***, then reregister the build agent with TFS.

If your build agent and TFS server, VS2017 are on the same machine, but the VS is installed after the build agent configured. Then reregister the build agent with TFS, since the system capabilities are only discovered when the agent is first configured -- any changes made after that are not captured.

More ways please refer this similar question:  [No agent could be found with the following capabilities: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840364/no-agent-could-be-found-with-the-following-capabilities-msbuild-visualstudio)

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the answer. I've reregister the Build Agent but it don't detect the VS2017. I'm running TFS 2015, does it support VS2017?

Comment: @vishgarg Yes. You could give a try with manually add the related capabilities. Detail ways please take a look at my reply in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605989/tfs-2015no-agent-could-be-found-with-the-following-capabilities-msbuild-visua/43630905#43630905

Comment: I've added the capabilities. Now when I'm building the project, it first shows the warning, Visual Studio not found and then an error comes:
MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.csproj(136,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Comment: @vishgarg v11.0 is VS2012. Seems you are trying to build a VS2012 project. Give a try with `/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0` in your msbuild argument. More details please refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718281/external-vs2013-build-error-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-path-was-not

Comment: Thanks Patrick-MSFT for the help. God bless you always :) 
One more thing I had to do after this, I had to manually copy the folder v15.0 from Visual Studio to the MSBuild folder. There are lot of changes in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: I've installed the latest release [v2.120.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases/tag/v2.120.2) of the agent, as pointed out by @MattSharpe above, but I'm still not getting the `vstest` capability. I'm running TFS 2017. Also: how to 'reregister' the build agent?

Comment: @InteXX In TFS 2017 (version 15.105.25910.0), if you choose latest, it would search for vs2015 and older versions, it doesn't support VS 2017.
We suggest you to upgrade to TFS 2017.1. In TFS 2017.1, in vstest task, you could choose 2.*(preview) version, then if you choose Latest as vs version, VS2017 would be found. More details please refer this  similar question in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19ca4c82-6dc6-47cc-a740-18c01b7d826e/new-build-server-unable-to-determine-the-location-of-vstestconsoleexe?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: Thanks @Patrick-MSFT. Could you weigh in on the questions I've posed in my conversation with Matt Sharpe above? I'm also trying to track it down [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/871).

Comment: I've learned that IDE installation is the only way to get `VSTest` as a working System Capability.

Comment: @InteXX Yes currently you have to install VS IDE to run the tests. According to the backlog , go with a 'tools installer' will come up soon in a few sprints