# SonarQube build errors in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube

Currently having the following errors on the "Complete the SonarQube analysis" step of our TFS 2017 build:

2017-12-05T22:04:24.5437340Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Get-TaskVariable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

2017-12-05T22:04:24.5837397Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner executable could not be found. Check that the build definition includes a SonarQube Pre-Build step ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner executable could not be found. Check that the build definition includes a SonarQube Pre-Build step

SonarQube version: Version 6.7 (build 33306)
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild version: 3.0.2

The "Prepare the SonarQube Analysis" step completes prior to the Visual Studio build step with no errors.

Comment: Do you use the latest SonarQube components in the TFS build definition?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error seems SonarQube.Runner  didn't captured by TFS build agent.

Double confirm the configuration in **SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis**  task which used  to prepare the analysis before executing the build. Such as **SonarQube Endpoint**.

Besides, on the build agent:

> - Make sure the .NET Framework v4.5.2+ is installed
> - Make sure the Java Runtime Environment 8 is installed
>
> Source Link: [Analyzing with SonarQube Extension for VSTS/TFS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS)

Try to create a new build definition with a simple test project to see if got the same error.

Comment: .NET Framework verison 4.7, Java Version 8 Update 111 installed on the agent. I am going to try building a new build agent server to see if that helps.

Comment: @KittHolland  Yes you should try these, since the system capabilities are only discovered when the agent is first configured -- any changes made after that are not captured. You need to reregister the build agent with TFS, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605989/tfs-2015no-agent-could-be-found-with-the-following-capabilities-msbuild-visua/43630905

Comment: That's really good information, thanks. Can you update the capabilities or do you have to reinstall? I will diff the capabilities when I get back to the office to confirm.

Comment: @KittHolland You don't have to reinstall this. After reconfigured or reinstalled build agent, TFS will auto captured and update those new capabilities  for the agent.

Comment: Hi @KittHolland, any update on this question, have you figured it out?